# PyQt/PySide SQLITE Pragma foreign_keys not working

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyside

Was somebody able to set Pragma foreign_keys = ON on SQLITE3 database using only tools from PyQt ?

Thanks!

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("./physio.db")
db.open()

query = QSqlQuery("PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1", db)
query.exec()
```

does nothing for me unfortunately.

Comment: What do you expect it to do? Running `query.exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys'); query.next(); print(query().value(0))` will output `1`. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: Interesting, you are correct on this (I did not use the next() method). Then the problem is that inserting record into a table with metod table_model.insertRecord() with invalid foreign key is anyway added into the table even though ideally it should erase some error ..

Comment: Please provide a [mre].